# Migrating NON CDB to PDB with minimal downtime

Tags: oracle, database-migration, oracle19c, pluggable-database

I am doing a migrating from 19.11 non-CDB on a local file system to 19.11 Pluggable Database (PDB) on Automatic Storage Management (ASM) on same server. I tested:

1. CREATE PDB WITH NOCOPY
2. DATAPUMP
3. CREATE EMPTY PDB and move data via db_link.

None of these are reducing downtime. I can not use "nocopy " approach as new datafiles needs to be created with ASM. Thinking of using "Step by Step Process of Migrating non-CDBs and PDBs Using ASM for file storage (Doc ID 1576755.1)" but it requires ASM on both NON CDB and new PDB. Also thinking of exploring if I can create a non-cdb standby with ASM for current NON-CDB database with filesystem and switch it to prod and convert that prod to PDB. Looking for solution with minimal downtime.

Comment: Can a PDB become standby of non-cdb ?

Answer (score 0):

"alter database move datafile" can be an online operation since 12, so I'd recommend doing this in 2 phases.

Phase 1 - convert your non-CDB local fs database to a non-CDB ASM database using the above commands.

Phase 2 - convert to PDB inplace.